# Selecionar registro de Ponto Eletrônico (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Como posso reunir apenas a primeira e ultima marcação, onde um funcionario possa ter X Marcações e até marcações no dia seguinte?

Conforme o exemplo abaixo

```
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| FUNC |  DATA  |ENTRADA| SAIDA |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
|000001|20180901| 07.20 | 17.20 |
|000001|20180902| 07.20 | 17.20 |
|000001|20180903| 07.20 | 17.20 |
|000001|20180904| 07.20 | 01.00 |
|000001|20180905| 07.20 | 16.00 |
|000001|20180906| 05.00 | 17.00 |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
```

Obs: a informção que pretendo obter é essa, será que da ?

**Dados**

*Dados em Texto*

```
+------+--------+-----+----+--------+
| FUNC |  DATA  |HORA | TM |DATAAPO |
+------+--------+-----+----+--------+
|000001|20180901|07.20| 1E |20180901|
|000001|20180901|17.20| 1S |20180901|
|000001|20180902|07.20| 1E |20180902|
|000001|20180902|12.00| 1S |20180902|
|000001|20180902|13.00|    |20180902|
|000001|20180902|17.20|    |20180902|
|000001|20180903|07.20| 1E |20180903|
|000001|20180903|12.00| 1S |20180903|
|000001|20180903|13.00| 2E |20180903|
|000001|20180903|17.20|    |20180903|
|000001|20180904|07.20|    |20180904|
|000001|20180905|01.00| 1S |20180904|
|000001|20180905|07.20| 1E |20180905|
|000001|20180905|16.00|    |20180905|
|000001|20180906|05.00|    |20180906|
|000001|20180906|12.00| 1S |20180906|
|000001|20180906|13.00|    |20180906|
|000001|20180906|17.00| 2S |20180906|
+------+--------+-----+----+--------+
```

Obs: Lembrando que em algumas ocasiões o TM não é preenchido com a informação de 1º e/ou 2º (Saída ou Entrada)

*Dados em Formato SQL*

```
CREATE TABLE FUNC (
 pFUNC varchar(6),
 pNOME varchar(100)
 );

insert into FUNC (pFUNC, pNOME) values
('000001','FULANO'),
('000002','BELTRANO'),
('000003','SICLANO')

CREATE TABLE PONTO (
 pFUNC varchar(6),
 pDATA varchar(8),
 pHORA float,
 pTM   varchar(2),
 pDTAPO varchar(8)
 );

insert into PONTO (pFUNC, pDATA, pHORA, pTM, pDTAPO) values
('000001','20180901', 7.20,'1E','20180901'),
('000001','20180901',17.20,'1S','20180901'),
('000001','20180902', 7.20,'1E','20180902'),
('000001','20180902',12.00,'1S','20180902'),
('000001','20180902',13.00,'  ','20180902'),
('000001','20180902',17.20,'  ','20180902'),
('000001','20180903', 7.20,'1E','20180903'),
('000001','20180903',12.00,'1S','20180903'),
('000001','20180903',13.00,'2E','20180903'),
('000001','20180903',17.20,'  ','20180903'),
('000001','20180904', 7.20,'  ','20180904'),
('000001','20180905', 1.00,'1S','20180904'),
('000001','20180905', 7.20,'1E','20180905'),
('000001','20180905',16.00,'  ','20180905'),
('000001','20180906', 5.00,'  ','20180906'),
('000001','20180906',12.00,'1S','20180906'),
('000001','20180906',13.00,'  ','20180906'),
('000001','20180906',17.00,'2S','20180906')
```

*Dados no SQLFiddle*

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f9f25/2

Qualquer duvida basta perguntar...

Comment: Qual é a diferença entre as colunas pDATA e pDTAPO?  Poderia explicar o que ocorreu nos dias 4 e 5?

Comment: pData é a data que foi realizando a marcação, pDTAPO é a data onde se deve considerar a marcação...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo resultado desejado me parece que a coluna de data a ser utilizada é a pDTAPO. Eis sugestão para avaliar:

```
-- código #1
SELECT pFUNC, pDTAPO, 
       min(case when right(pTM,1) = 'E' then pHORA end) as ENTRADA,
       max(case when right(pTM,1) = 'S' then pHORA end) as SAIDA
  from PONTO
  group by pFUNC, pDTAPO;
```

Se as colunas pDATA e pDTAPO terão sempre 8 caracteres, sugiro que as declare como char(8).

---

Se for necessário ignorar a coluna pTM, temos:

```
-- código #2
SELECT pFUNC, pDTAPO, 
       min(pHORA) as ENTRADA,
       max(pHORA) as SAIDA
  from PONTO
  group by pFUNC, pDTAPO;
```

Entretanto a confiabilidade do resultado é reduzida para os casos em que ocorra quebra (por exemplo, entrada sem saída ou vice-versa), pois o resultado pode ficar errado (ou não) para aquele dia.

---

Considerando-se a informação complementar de que um turno pode iniciar em um dia e terminar em outro, eis sugestão:

```
-- código #3
with pontoDataHora as (
SELECT pFUNC, pDTAPO, 
       datetimefromparts(left(pDATA, 4), 
                         substring(pDATA, 5, 2),
                         substring(pDATA, 7, 2),
                         round(pHORA, 0, 1),
                         cast((pHORA * 100) as int) % 100,
                         0, 0) as pDATAHORA
  from PONTO
) 
SELECT pFUNC, pDTAPO, 
       min(pDATAHORA) as ENTRADA,
       max(pDATAHORA) as SAIDA
  from pontoDataHora
  group by pFUNC, pDTAPO;
```

Assim como no código #2, a confiabilidade do resultado é reduzida para os casos em que ocorra quebra (por exemplo, entrada sem saída ou vice-versa), pois o resultado pode ficar errado (ou não) para aquele dia. O erro não está no código mas sim nos dados.

Comment: Percebi um detalhe importante, encontrei algumas marcações onde o pTM está em branco, ai essa query até funcionaria se não estivesse em branco.

Comment: Roberto, (1) se a coluna pTM estiver em branco, como saber se a marcação é de entrada ou de saída? (2) O que significa "em branco": vazia, "  " ou sem informação (NULL)? (3) Quando não há informação se o horário é de entrada ou de saída, o que deve ser feito (qual é a regra)?

Comment: Bom dia José, (1) é justamente essa minha dificuldade (2) em branco é vazio " " [2 espaços em branco] (3) o sistema identifica normalmente o que é de entrada e saída, porém o relatório que estou fazendo de absenteísmo está falho por causa dessa situação. Obs: Existe uma tabela onde tem os horários de cada turno, isso ajudaria ?

Comment: Roberto, acrescentei uma segunda opção. Quanto à tabela de turno, ela pode ser útil sim.

Comment: Jose, também já tentei desta forma igual ao "código #2" porém ele se perder quando o registro é realizado depois da meia noite, o min vira o max e o max vira o minimo...

Comment: Roberto, se o turno pode virar dia então é necessário outra abordagem; vide código #3. Sugiro que acrescente essa informação na descrição do problema.

Comment: mas essa informação já tem, observe o dia 04, a pessoa entra de 07:20 e sai de 01:00 da manhã